# HTTP Error 404.0 Not Found MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My project in mvc4 and working with Entity framework 5.0 , I have a self referencing association table , want to view EmployeeName and his/here managerName so I creates a class

```
public class Employee 
{
   Public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
   Public string ManagerName {get; set;}
}
```

and this is my controller ...

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller 
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      var result = db.empMgr.Select(x => new Employee
      {
         EmployeeName = x.EmployeeName,
         ManagerName = x.empMgr1.EmployeeName
      });
      return View(result);
   }
}
```

and this is razor ...

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ManagerName)</td>
   </tr>
}
```

after running this link

> www.localhost/Employee/Index

The following error found

> > 404 - File or directory not found.
> >     The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is     temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Did you try without www ?

Comment: yes .. even when running localhost:4052/Employee/Index Error still appear

Comment: You are missing the port number for localhost. It should be like http://localhost:6916/Employee/Index

Comment: actually try this but error still appear !

Comment: What's the *exact* URL you're trying?  How are your routes defined in the application?

Comment: You need to create an app in your IIS and set the location of that as the published location of your web app and access it like `localhost/yourAppName/Employee/Index`

Comment: @David this is the link I tried > localhost:4052/Employee/Index 
.. and the only route is the default route 'routes.MapRoute(name:Default),url: " {Controller} /{action} / {id} " , defaults : new { controller = "Home " , action = "Index" , id = UrlParameter.Optional } ); '

Comment: Breakpoint/debug inside of the controller.  Does the app get to the action code, or is the 404 thrown by the routing?  Could be controller, could be view... lets figure out which.